# Connect to sqlite3.Connection using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am using a library that creates an SQLite library in-memory by calling `sqlite3.connect(':memory:')`. I would like to connect to this database using `sqlalchemy` to use some ORM and other nice bells and whistles. Is there, in the depths of SQLAlchemy's API, a way to pass the resulting `sqlite3.Connection` object through so that I can re-use it?

I cannot just re-connect with `connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:').connect()` – as the [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) states: “The database ceases to exist as soon as the database connection is closed. Every :memory: database is distinct from every other. So, opening two database connections each with the filename ":memory:" will create two independent in-memory databases.” (Which makes sense. I also tried it, and the behaviour is as expected.)

I have tried to follow SQLAlchemy's source code to find the low level location where the database connection is established and SQLite is actually called, but so far I found nothing. It looks like SQLAlchemy uses far too much obscure alchemy to do that for me to understand when and where it happens.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do that:

```
# some connection is created - by you or someone else 
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

... 

def get_connection():
    # just a debug print to verify that it's indeed getting called:
    print("returning the connection") 
    return conn

# create a SQL Alchamy engine that uses the same in-memory sqlite connection
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', creator = get_connection)
```

From this point on, just use the engine as you wish.

Here's [a link to the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.creator) of this feature.